# Order of Endings in NG for Sekiro

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

So, I have finally reached the end of my first playthrough of Sekiro, and I have set myself up for choosing one of 3 endings (the "Shura" ending excluded). However, I'm not sure which ending I should choose.

**In terms of difficulty, as I progress through NG, which endings in what order would be easiest to achieve?**

For example, Shura would be the easiest ending to achieve, but then I would have to do all the prep for the other ending(s) in NG+ and above. The Dragon's Homecoming ending is the most convoluted, but doesn't require additional bossfights (I.e. Father Owl to retrieve the Aromatic Flower from the alternate Hirata Estate Memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question when I was getting the Platinum Trophy. I found that the easiest way to get all the endings (in the same save) is by following this order:

- Purification (hardest because you need to beat Owl (Father)). I also recommend you to beat the [Demon of Hatred](https://sekiroshadowsdietwice.wiki.fextralife.com/Demon+of+Hatred) in your first new game [NG].
- Return [NG+].
- Immortal Severance [NG+1].
- Shura [NG+2].

There is a very nice guide to obtain each ending in [this link](https://sekiroshadowsdietwice.wiki.fextralife.com/Endings).

Starting on NG+, you may hit the wall with some bosses. If that happens, I strongly recommend you to practice using the Free DLC [Reflections of Strength](https://sekiroshadowsdietwice.wiki.fextralife.com/Reflections+of+Strength). In my case, I need to practice dozens of times the fight with [Isshin, The Sword Saint](https://sekiroshadowsdietwice.wiki.fextralife.com/Isshin,+the+Sword+Saint) before I was able to defeat it successfully in NG+ and beyond.